# Need help with button layout on small device

Tags: buttons, layout, design, responsive-design, bootstrap

I have the following button layout on my web app and it looks fine on larger screens..
[image]

On portrait iPad or smaller it looks like this..
[image]

I'm not sure what the best way to display, hide/show these would be?
Smaller icons, hamburger menu, stack vertically on a grid?

All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Could please describe a bit more on what your application is doing? Are all the buttons equally important for your user?

Comment: This page is a client profile on a client management app, the edit button has highest importance as it contains multiple actions, same with the tag button. all others couple probably be grouped together in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you *could* just let them wrap, like they are in your screenshot, albeit with some margin added between the rows.

If some are used less frequently than others, and if there is a logical way to group and label those options in dropdowns, that's probably a good way to simplify things. But don't necessarily do that just for smaller screens - if it makes sense to group things on smaller screens, it might make sense to group them on larger screens too.

This question is a prime candidate for card sorting or other usability testing if you are able.